# TYPO3 News: add class if Media Element has video item

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

I need to add class to News item if Relations tab has a video element.

```
<f:if condition="{mediaElement.type} == 2">
    <div class="news-video">preview image</div>
 </f:if>
```

My question is how to change this code to check if the news has a video element in relation tab, if yes add class"news-video" to the div

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: My question is how to change this code to check if the news has a video element in relation tab, if yes add class"news-video" to the div

Answer (score 0):

The [video-filetype number is 4](https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/master/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_resource_1_1_abstract_file.html), not 2.

You can generate the class via for-each:

```
<div 
    <f:if condition="{newsItem.relatedFiles}">
        class="
        <f:for each="{newsItem.relatedFiles}" as="relatedFile">
            <f:if condition="{relatedFile.originalResource.type} == 4">
                news-video
            </f:if>
        </f:for>
        "
    </f:if>
>
preview image
</div>
```

One side effect is that the class will be repeated for every video element:

*class="news-video news-video news-video"*

This [is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26341507/can-an-html-element-have-the-same-attribute-twice).

To avoid this you could enhance the code by [adding a counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44259106/typo3-count-up-inside-fluid) and skip all repetitions or just generate the class afterwards if your counter is >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine a variable viewhelper with an if condition and a loop like this:

```
<f:if condition="{newsItem.relatedFiles}">
    <f:for each="{newsItem.relatedFiles}" as="relatedFile">
        <f:if condition="{relatedFile.originalResource.type} == 2">
            <f:variable name=”newsVideo”>1</f:variable>
        </f:if>
    </f:for>
</f:if>
<div{f:if(condition: '{newsVideo}', then: ' class="news-video"')}>preview image</div>
```